# How can I insert python code into a function on another file?

Tags: python-3.x

Good evening, I've been working on some automation software and I have hit a little snag, so I need to create a dataframe from an old dataframe. However, my problem is that the self.new_df lines need to go into a separate file. The number of these lines needs to be modular and change depending on circumstance.  example:

file_1

```
class mapping: 
   __def__(self,new_df,df)):
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   
   def map_df():
      self.new_df['column1'] = ''
      self.new_df['column2'] = self.df['column2b']
      self.new_df['column3'] = VARIABLE_ONE
```

Needs to turn into:

file_1

```
import file_2 as f2

class mapping: 
   __def__(self,new_df,df,block_quote):
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

   def map_df():
      f2.block_quote
```

file_2

```
block_quote =       
      self.new_df['column1'] = ''
      self.new_df['column2'] = self.df['column2b']
      self.new_df['column3'] = VARIABLE_ONE
```

Long story short, I am the only one who knows python so we need one file to remain untouched and another just to store variables, dictionaries, and perhaps the occasional function so that it is easy for someone without python experience could update the mappings. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
from file_2 import block_quote
class mapping: 
   __def__(self,new_df,df,block_quote):
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

   def map_df():
      f2=block_quote(new_df, df)

#file_2
def block_quote(new_df, df):
       
      new_df['column1'] = ''
      new_df['column2'] = self.df['column2b']
      new_df['column3'] = VARIABLE_ONE 
      return new_df
```

or generate a function t